# Retrieve contact details from Contact Application

Tags: android, contacts

I am implementing a phonebook application and i want the user to be able to import to my app a contact from the Contacts Application that is already installed in Android. The problem is that i cannot retrieve the value of the email of the contact i choose from the list.

I use the following code to open the contacts application

```
Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
pickContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers
startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
```

and in onActivityResult i use the following code to get the data of the contact i chose from the contact list:

```
Uri contactUri = data.getData();

        String[] projection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                .query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
        String number = cursor.getString(column);

        int column1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS);
        String email= cursor.getString(column1);

        int column2 = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
                String fullName = cursor.getString(column2);
```

but the "email" variable contains the same value with the phone number of the contact. What could be wrong?

Moreover, the Phone.DISPLAY_NAME column of the cursor contains the full Name of the contact.(firstName, middleName and lastName). Is there a way to get those fields separately? Now i use split(" ") function to separate them.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for the email here:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-essentials-using-the-contact-picker--mobile-2017